# How to debug Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I am using the Code First Migration in my project.

In the first migration file we are executing the .sql files, these are executing perfectly.

But when I execute the new .sql file in the latest migration file those are not execute and there is no error in the package manager console.

Is there a way to debug the migration file step by step?

Thanks